# Name of this type of equation and solutions to solve it iteratively?

Tags: matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations

I have the equation of the form:

$$
\textbf{X}_{n+1} = \textbf{X}_{n} + \textbf{X}_{0}
$$

This equation come from physical optics when trying to solve the MFIE (below) iteratively.

$$
\textbf{J}(\textbf{r}) = 2\vec{n} \times \textbf{H}^{inc}(\textbf{r}) + 2\vec{n} \times \textbf{H}(\textbf{r})
$$

Where $\vec{X}_{0}$ is my incident plane wave (This remains a constant vector) and the $\vec{X}_{n}$ is the current which has been calcuated. The sum of these gives the next iteration of the current, $\vec{X}_{n+1}$. This was just some background to help get a better picture.

My questions are:

1. What type of equation is this?
2. What methods are there to solve an equation like this iteratively? Some of the methods I have looked at are only valid for linear equations of this type, $Ax = b$.

Comment: I would look at methods that solve matrix equations for system of difference equations, namely the implicit numerical schemes. As you can imagine alot of time dependent equations require solve equations of the form above. Set your initial matrix i.e $n=0$ and then solve as if the r.h.s was constant.

Comment: Do you think that time matters here ?

Answer (score 1):

This ''vectorial affine recurrence relationship'' (such is ''a'' name that can be given):

$$\tag{1}V_{n+1}=AV_{n}+b$$

has a standard method of resolution.

First of all, look at the ''candidate vector'' say $V_{\infty}$ that will be the limit if any. $V_{\infty}$ should verify the fixed point equation:

$$\tag{2}V_{\infty} \ = \ A V_{\infty}+b$$

(and $V_{\infty}$ will be found as a solution to the equivalent linear system $(I_n-A)V_{\infty}=b$).

Now, make the subtraction (1)-(2):

$$\tag{3}V_{n+1}-V_{\infty} \ = \ A(V_{n+1}-V_{\infty})$$

where $b$ has disappeared; (3) can be written so, with an auxiliary sequence:

$$\tag{4}W_{n+1} \ = \ A W_{n+1} \ \ \text{with} \ \ W_{n}:=V_{n}-V_{\infty}$$

We are now faced with a classical problem, with a discussion on the eigenvalues of $A$:

Let us call ''spectral radius'' (and denote by $r$) the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $A$:

- if $r<1$, $W_n \to 0$, then $V_n \to V_{\infty}$.
- if $r>1$ $W_n$ is divergent, then $V_n$ is divergent.
- if $r=1$, different cases may arise but in general there is no convergence either

(for example if there is an eigenvalue equal to -1, one can observe permanent oscillations).

Comment: Have you just converted it to a normal system of linear equations in (4)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean for (4) which is not truly speaking system of linear equations. Could you explain a little more ?

Comment: Maybe, by giving some more context, I could understand better your needs. By the way, what is the dimension of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$ n=2,3 ....?